# ImportError: No Module named xlwt

Tags: python, importerror, python-import

My sytem:  Windows, Python 2.7

I downloaded a package and want to include it in my script.

After I unzipped the package, here is my folder structure:

- Work

  - xlwt-0.7.3   (contains a `setup.py`)

    - xlwt     (contains `__init__.py` among others)

My script runs from the top-level (Work) folder.

Using `import xlwt` in my script produces:

```
ImportError: No Module named xlwt
```

How do I import xlwt?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

First off, try using easy_install or pip to install it into your pythonpath:

```
easy_install xlwt
```

or

```
pip install xlwt
```

These are python package managers/installers and make the whole process so much easier. But if you have already downloaded it manually, you still need to install it:

```
python setup.py install
```

Then it will be available in your python path for import. If you find that you don't have easy_install, manually download this: http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py and do `python ez_setup.py`, and then continue the instructions. Best choice though is to install pip and use it for your package installations. If you have easy_install, but not pip, you can do `easy_install pip`

Comment: for easy_install command, first install  setup tools:
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools