# cant import python module with standard methods

Tags: python, pip, package, easy-install, xlwt

**System**

- Win7 64bit
- Python in two locations:

  - C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python
  - C:\Python
- IDE is Spyder downloaded with WinPython
- Package manager is WinPython Control Panel

**Problem**

Trying to import the module xlwt using the methods mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848299/importerror-no-module-named-xlwt)

- pip is throwing an error that it can't find "**main**"
- easy_install seems to work but still cant "import xlwt" in python
- manual install is the same as easy_install above
- install through package manager is showing no errors

All these approaches have been tried in both locations of the python installation with and with admin privileges.

Does anyone see what I am missing? Thanks

Comment: what's the output from `echo %PATH%` in windows command prompt? Also try running your scripts without `Spyder`, I've seen a few questions the last few weeks that has odd behaviours in Spyder and it appears to cause a lot of issues.

Comment: Which Python are you using?  Having two locations will only serve to confuse, I suggest you uninstall one of them - unless you have a good reason for having two.  Check your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

Comment: tried running in IDLE as well, no luck.  Tried importing in cmd > python and it works! The PATH for python is C:\Python\python-3.4.3.amd64\Scripts; How do I get the PYTHONPATH?

Comment: PYTHONPATH is an environment variable, you get it in the same way as any other environment variable on Windows.  You can use the GUI, or on `cmd.exe` type `echo %PYTHONPATH%`.  If you want to see all your environment variables, on `cmd.exe` type `SET`.  My best guess for your problem is that you are installing into one python environment but running the other.  Why do you have two?

Comment: ok it seems that it is unset as it is only echoing "%PYTHONPATH%" would I need this even though I have set a python path in the PATH env variable?